# Hive - external tables and csv data

Tags: csv, import, hive

I need some help from you with a problem of understanding refrencing data from hive. The following situation: I have a CSV fil data.csv imported into hadoop. Now I have found many snippets that use an external table to create a schema on top of the csv file. My question is, how does hive know that the schema of the external table is connected to data.csv. In examples I cannot find a reference to the csv file.

Where is sample_1.csv referenced for usage in [this hive example](https://bigdataprogrammers.com/load-csv-file-into-hive-orc-table/) or how does hive know that data from sample_1.csv includes the data?

Answer (score 2):

While creating external table we have to give the list of columns and hdfs location. Hive will store only column metadata like column name, datatype.. and the hdfs location.

When we execute query on external table it will fetch metadata and then fetch available files from hdfs location.

Comment: Hi, tahnk you! The linked example uses folowing query:
    CREATE SCHEMA IF NOT EXISTS bdp;
    CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE IF NOT EXISTS bdp.hv_csv_table
    (id STRING,Code STRING)
    ROW FORMAT DELIMITED
    FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
    STORED AS TEXTFILE
    LOCATION 'hdfs://sandbox.hortonworks.com:8020/user/root/bdp/ld_csv_hv/ip';

The location seems to be a directory not a file.     It is not understandable to me how hive does know what the source is.

Answer (score 0):

now we've got the answer. The manual recommends to store one file in one directory. When we then build an external table on top it seems that the data ist identified by the schema.

In my Testcase i have imorted 3 csv files with one schema 2 files got the matching schema. The third file got one column more. If i run a query the data of all three files are shown. The additional column from the third file is missing.

Everything is fine now - thank you!